# Matching end of string or ; in regex

Tags: python, regex

Why does the following regex doesn't match the last occurrence of the search word?

```
(?i)(^|,|;)\s*old\s*($|;)
```

This matches the first and second `old`, but not the third:

```
One,old;Two,old;old
     ^       ^   ^
   match   match  \_ no match
```

However, if I remove the last `;` (`(?i)(^|,|;)\s*old\s*$`), it does match the last occurrence.

P.S. I'm using Python.

Comment: Because in this part `($|;)` you are consuming the character `;` Did you mean like this with the capture group also arond `old` ? `(?:^|[,;])\s*(old)\s*(?=$|;)` https://regex101.com/r/piuYvG/1

Comment: I want to be able to replace the captured word ``old``. That's why I was capturing the last group.

Comment: Then it will be like like this `(^|[,;])\s*old\s*(?=$|;)` https://regex101.com/r/x3oF4M/1

Comment: Yes, a common case where the consuming pattern must be turned into a non-consuming, since matches overlap.

Comment: Why are you using a regexp for this instead of `split()`?

Comment: @Barmar This is in a pandas dataframe, and the length of the string varies between records.

Comment: Why not just use `\bold\b`?

Comment: @Nick for my use case, `\b` doesn’t work since `old` might appear elsewhere.

Comment: @jak123 your question doesn't make that clear. Without complete information you won't get as good an answer as you might otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could capture what comes before it `(^|[,;])` match what you want to replace and assert `(?=$|;)` what should be to the right.

For the comma and the semicolon you can use a character class.

In the replacement use the capture group `\1`

```
(^|[,;])\s*old\s*(?=$|;)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/x3oF4M/1)